# Export a python program with scripts that involves a local path

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

[My code that contains the path to the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCTyg.png)

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options, executable_path="D:\chromedriver.exe")`

As far as I'm concerned, I have to specify the path to chromedriver when using Selenium on Python. How do I export my code to an .exe file so that I can use it in other PCs that don't have chromedriver downloaded and installed at D:?
Or are there any way to use selenium without chromedriver?
Thank you.

Comment: Make the path a runtime parameter (`argparse`) and instruct the user to supply the relevant location when invoking the program. And no, Selenium cannot work without a browser driver , because its whole purpose is to get the browser to render the webpage for your code to inspect.

Comment: Try to use https://playwright.dev/python/ it download browsers automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [webdriver-manager](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager) library, it will download and set up the driver automatically depending on your os. With this, you don't have to worry about setting up the driver.

It's very easy to set up, with chrome -

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

with firefox -

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
```